# Get the total number of rows from two different tables with the same id drops me more rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello i need help by getting the total number of rows of two different tables with the same id, this is my query

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM correccion a, 
     acciones b 
WHERE a.id_acp =  '361838021102014' 
AND b.id_acp =  '361838021102014'
```

This query returns 10 but the table correccion has 5 rows and the table acciones has 2 rows, it should be 7, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you are getting is a Cartesian product, every row from a is matched to every possible row from b, giving you the answer of 10 (5x2).

You need to do this:

```
SELECT a.a+b.b as count
FROM (
SELECT count(*) as a
from correccion
where id_acp = '361838021102014'
) a,
(
SELECT count(*) as b
from acciones
where id_acp = '361838021102014' 
) b
```

Comment: this is almost the right answer, every derived table should have his own alias

Comment: SELECT c.a+d.b as count
FROM (
SELECT count(*) as a
from correccion
where id_acp = '361838021102014'
) as c,
(
SELECT count(*) as b
from acciones
where id_acp = '361838021102014' 
) as d

Comment: Yeah, using `a` and `b` again, was probably a little confusing. Anyway, you get the idea!